# What is the purpose of "post" in Matlab's padarray function?

Tags: arrays, matlab, pad

In Matlab, there is a function called [padarray](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/padarray.html). I didn't understand the `"post"` value of the function. Can you describe it in terms of an example?

Comment: 1.  Just try it.  2. If you don't understand what the function does, you don't need it

Comment: Seems you do not want to give the documentation a try.

Answer (score 1):

So I will try to be clear:

```
A = magic(2);
A =

 1     3
 4     2
B = padarray(A,[0 1],'circular','post')
B =

 1     3     1
 4     2     4
```

`post` only pads after the last array element along each dimension: in this particular case, only along dimension `2` because of `[0 1]` as second input in `padarray`.

**P.S.:** MATLAB user manual is usually quite plenty of examples about any built-in function.